# Will uninstalling Android Studio delete my projects?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having problems updating Android Studio and I'm considering uninstalling it, then re-installing it just to get the update. If I uninstall Android Studio, will my current projects be deleted?

-Thanks!

Comment: Also, keep Android Studio separate from the Android SDK. I know that on a Mac, it's somewhat frustrating to have both in the same folder (while on PCs, it's no trouble at all).

Comment: Hell no! That would be a disaster implementation from Google.

Comment: It's not mandatory that you do it, but if you keep on deleting Android Studio for whatever reason, it's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are independent. Just make sure you keep them in different folders.

Comment: Nathan, If you want to know where your project is stored, right-click on it and select "Reveal in Finder".